# Select only largest values in a SQL relation?

Tags: sql, max

I have the following two relations:

```
Game(id, name, year)
Devs(pid, gid, role)
```

Where Game.id is a primary key, and where Devs.gid is a foreign key to Game.id.

I want to write a SQL query that finds the game with the largest amount of people who worked on that game. I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT Game.name, count(DISTINCT Devs.pid)
FROM Game, Devs
WHERE Devs.gid=Game.id
GROUP BY Devs.gid, Game.name
ORDER BY count(Devs.pid) DESC;
```

This query sort of accomplishes my goal, in the sense that it returns all of the Games in the relation sorted by the number of people who worked on each game, but I'm trying to modify this query so that it does two things. One, it should only return the game with the most people who worked on it, and two, if there are two games that had an equal amount of people work on them, it should return both of those games. I know that if I replace the top line like so:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Game.name, count(DISTINCT Devs.pid)
```

Then it accomplishes my first goal, but if there are two games that both have the highest number of people who worked on them, then it only returns one of those games. How can I go about changing this query so that it will return all games with the highest number of people that worked on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task can be shorten to:

> Give me all the rows from the original query with the maximum number of developers

It can be reached through the `WITH` [statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx). The answer is the following:

```
WITH GamesDevs (GameName, DevsCount)
AS
(
    SELECT Game.name AS GameName, count(DISTINCT Devs.pid) AS DevsCount
    FROM Game, Devs
    WHERE Devs.gid=Game.id
    GROUP BY Devs.gid, Game.name
    ORDER BY count(Devs.pid) DESC 
)

SELECT * FROM GamesDevs WHERE GamesDevs.DevsCount = (SELECT MAX(DevsCount) FROM GamesDevs)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This seems to work! Would you mind expanding on how this query works though? I'm having a hard time understanding it.

Comment: Well, the problem might be described as `give me all the rows with the maximum number of developers`. Thus, we described your query as `GamesDevs` through `WITH` statement (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) and then selected all the rows with the maximum number of developers.

Comment: Is there an equivalent way of writing this without the WITH clause? I'm only a few weeks into learning SQL and it's kind of hurting my head haha.

Comment: I think the other answers are good also. The second thing that appeared in my head was about HAVING - the @Dhaval answer.

Comment: If you are new in SQL my answer is going to be the simplest. Don't be afraid of `WITH` statement - you can think about it as about table. In our case `GamesDevs` can be represented as the another table that contains the data from your original query.

Comment: Gotcha. I'll have to do some reading up on the WITH clause then haha. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try this query :

```
  select g.name, count(d.gid)
  from 
  game g 
    join 
  devs d 
  on g.id=d.gid
  group by g.name 
  having count(d.gid)= (select max (temp.cnt) from 
      (select gid p, count(*) cnt 
       from devs 
       group by gid) temp)
  ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `with ties` syntax, if that's the only thing that isn't working:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx

```
select      top 1 with ties
            game.name,
            count(distinct devs.pid)
from        game
       join devs
         on devs.gid = game.id
group by    devs.gid,
            game.name
order by    3 desc
```

Also consider modern join syntax.

Comment: I think you need to include an `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 1):

This should also work :)

```
SELECT Game.name, count(DISTINCT Devs.pid)
FROM Game, Devs
WHERE Devs.gid=Game.id
GROUP BY Devs.gid, Game.name
Having count(DISTINCT Devs.pid) = Max(count(DISTINCT Devs.pid))
ORDER BY count(Devs.pid) DESC;
```

Comment: This will not work, as you cannot perform an aggregate function, i.e. `MAX` on an expression containing another aggregate function, i.e. `COUNT`