# Rewriting WITH statements into subquery statements in SQL?

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, with-statement

I have the following two relations:

```
Game(id, name, year)
Devs(pid, gid, role)
```

Where Game.id is a primary key, and where Devs.gid is a foreign key to Game.id.

In a [previous post I made here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29787954/select-only-largest-values-in-a-sql-relation), another user was kind enough to help me out in creating a query that finds all games made with the most developers making that game. His answer used a WITH statement, and I am not very familiar with these as I'm only a few weeks into learning SQL. Here's the working query:

```
WITH GamesDevs (GameName, DevsCount)
AS
(
    SELECT Game.name AS GameName, count(DISTINCT Devs.pid) AS DevsCount
    FROM Game, Devs
    WHERE Devs.gid=Game.id
    GROUP BY Devs.gid, Game.name
)

SELECT * FROM GamesDevs WHERE GamesDevs.DevsCount = (SELECT MAX(DevsCount) FROM GamesDevs)
```

For the sole purpose of getting more familiar with SQL, I am trying to rewrite this query using a subquery instead of a WITH statement. I've been using [this Oracle documentation](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause.php) to help me figure it out. I tried rewriting the query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT Game.name AS GameName, count(DISTINCT Devs.pid) AS DevsCount
    FROM Game, Devs
    WHERE Devs.gid=Game.id
    GROUP BY Devs.gid, Game.name) GamesDevs
WHERE GamesDevs.DevsCount = (SELECT MAX(DevsCount) FROM GamesDevs)
```

As far as I can tell, these two queries should be identical. However, when I try running the second query, I get the error

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6 Invalid column name 'DevsCount'.

Does anyone know why I might be getting this error, or why these two queries wouldn't be identical?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am working on the Microsoft Azure Cloud!

Comment: You will need to duplicate that subquery in last from clause

Comment: You say you're new to SQL? Good, then you shouldn't have too much to undo: [Bad habits to kick: using old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to duplicate that subquery in last from clause like:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT Game.name AS GameName, count(DISTINCT Devs.pid) AS DevsCount
    FROM Game, Devs
    WHERE Devs.gid=Game.id
    GROUP BY Devs.gid, Game.name) GamesDevs
WHERE GamesDevs.DevsCount = (SELECT MAX(DevsCount) FROM (SELECT Game.name AS GameName, count(DISTINCT Devs.pid) AS DevsCount
    FROM Game
    INNER JOIN Devs ON Devs.gid=Game.id
    GROUP BY Devs.gid, Game.name))
```

But better do it like:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES Game.name AS GameName, count(DISTINCT Devs.pid) AS DevsCount
FROM Game
INNER JOIN Devs ON Devs.gid=Game.id
GROUP BY Devs.gid, Game.name
ORDER BY DevsCount DESC
```

Comment: @Turophile - are you sure? So far as I'm aware, `GROUP` is logically processed before `SELECT` is, so there shouldn't be any dependencies in that direction.

Comment: Thank you! I did find that on the last line, I needed to change it to `GROUP BY DEVS.gid, GAME.name) GamesDevs)` in order for it to work though. Why does the subquery need to be duplicated though?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I thought this was the case but I learnt SQL many years ago and there have been many syntax changes and new variants of SQL since then. Also, I could just be flat out wrong. I will delete my comment to avoid confusing anyone.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

```
WHERE GamesDevs.DevsCount = (SELECT MAX(DevsCount) FROM GamesDevs)
```

From a CTE you select twice. But you can not from a sub query. 
The first statement

```
WHERE GamesDevs.DevsCount
```

is correct. But

```
(SELECT MAX(DevsCount) FROM GamesDevs)
```

is not correct because you can reuse the subquery. Selecting from the cte which is acting like a view works that is why you can use both a max and compare the count

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RANK` window function in the subquery in order to locate those records having the largest count of distinct developers per game:

```
SELECT GameName, DevsCount
FROM (
   SELECT Game.name AS GameName, 
          COUNT(DISTINCT Devs.pid) AS DevsCount,
          RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT Devs.pid) DESC) AS rnk
   FROM Game
   INNER JOIN Devs ON Game.id = Devs.gid
   GROUP BY Devs.gid, Game.name ) t
WHERE t.rnk = 1
```

This way you don't have to repeat the `SELECT MAX(DevsCount)` query. You only have to select those records having `rnk = 1`.

You should also consider using [ANSI-standard SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)  to specify the exact type of `JOIN` operation you are using.

@Giorgi's answer that proposes using `SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES` is a much cleaner solution to your original problem. I just made this post as an alternative way to correct the subquery you are using.